# fix: mismatch between extentref entry reference count

Tags: disk-utility, catalina, filesystem, apfs

My MacBookPro 2019 (Catalina 10.15.4) recently started to show weird issues in disk utility:

When validating the internal startup disk (SSD) it fails various times with:

```
mismatch between extentref entry reference count
```

What can I do to fix this? Is this a serious issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a serious issue? Maybe...

It is an issue with your disk that needs to be run in an environment where the normal boot volume is not the active startup volume. Fortunately that is built into all recent Macs.

**FIRST,** you have a recent backup, right? If not and you can make a backup, do so now.

Now boot into recovery mode by holding the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> keys during a reboot. Eventually you will get to a screen (if memory serves...) that asks you to pick a language and then you get the recovery environment.

Go to the (I believe) Tools menu and select Disk Utility. Now select the HD that you boot from and click on repair.

Depending on what is wrong and how fixable it is this might take a few minutes. It also might take an hour or more. Let it do its thing. Hopefully it can repair the error.

**Note:** as the OP mentioned sometimes running Disk Utility a few times will fix it on subsequent attempts. So try it again, and maybe again and again.

If it can't repair the error... Well normally I would advise using DiskWarrior (or other disk repair utilities) but I am not aware of any 3rd party disk repair utilities that work on APFS. Perhaps someone else in the AskDifferent community knows of one...

If there isn't one you basically should check your backup (make sure you have everything) and then reformat the disk and reinstall from scratch and then restore your backup. Why? Well if you have a disk error that Disk Utility can't fix and there are no 3rd party utilities then all you can do is reformat, reinstall and restore.

Comment: I already tried to use single user mode. Unfortunately trying to repair there doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: After retrying it a couple of more times in regular and recovery mode the error messages have gone away and are fixed.

Comment: Something I neglected to add, run Disk Utility a few times and *sometimes* it will fix it on subsequent attempts.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be too concerned about this error. I got the same errors multiple times during disk check on MBP 15" mid-2015 using Big Sur 11.5.1 even in recovery mode. After upgrading macOS to the latest version (11.5.2) the errors disappeared and Disk Utility first aid finished successfully. Seems that it had to do something with snapshots since after the upgrade there were only 2 snapshots whereas before there were 15.

Answer (score 1):

Time Machine backup started failing on specific file after a long delay (hours) so I ran first aid live reporting errors which it couldn't repair without recovery mode so I did the following:

1. Boot into recovery mode by pressing <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> during startup
2. Start `Disk Utility` from the main menu of the recovery mode
3. By default only volumes are visible so select Disk Utility menu item `View` -> `Show All Devices` to show containers
4. Select the **container** (*APFS Container*) on the left-hand side of the volume list (just below the name/model of the physical device/disk) e.g. "AppleAPFSMedia"/"Container disk3"
5. Run first aid on the container which can take hours and multiple rounds to complete. (First aid automatically triggers another round after repairs if needed.)

This was successful using macOS Monterey and a 2 TB Samsung SSD. First I ran it on a single volume but first aid couldn't repair it separately and unfortunately the containers are hidden by default in the Disk Utility in recovery mode.